# Can I run "Mesh ‣ Clean up ‣ ..." tools without tabbing into edit mode?

Tags: mesh

I have an ENORMOUS mesh (23 million faces) that I'm interested in cleaning up. I've already gotten everything I can out of the modifier stack, and now I see some "Mesh -> Clean up" tools that I'd like to try out... but I can only access them in edit mode.

Switching to edit mode with a model this big is prohibitively demanding on my system, so it would be great if I could exercise these tools on my mesh some other way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe a mask modifier would be useful? Would at least remove all or selected parts from calculation for time being and can be used in edit mode with vertex groups.

Comment: That will be a helpful solution, if there are certain parts of my model that I want to process, without having to process the whole thing. At this point, I'm more interested in a way (perhaps a Python script?) to exercise the Mesh Tools on the whole mesh... but without having to enter Edit Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the cleanup operations can be done through modifiers:

- Decimate Geometry > *Decimate Modifier* (Collapse)
- Limited Dissolve > *Decimate modifier* (Planar)
- Merge By Distance > *Weld Modifier*

<sup>(Didn't feel right without a silly gif)</sup>
[image]

Comment: The modifiers are great, but I've already exhausted their usefulness. I'm interested in experimenting with the Mesh Clean Up tools that don't have a modifier counterpart. Incidentally, I also want to see if the clean up tools behave the same way as their modifier counterparts.